# getElementsByClassName Reference

Tags: javascript

I have spent hours trying to find a reference for what is available from `getElementsByClassName`.  Several sources say it returns an HTML collection of item, length and nameditem yet w3schools shows this example where innerHTML is used:

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
x[0].innerHTML = "Hello World!";

What else is available and where can I find it?  Is there a reference that shows what can be used with `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName. And the example you cite is simply getting one specific element via `[0]` and changing its innerHTML property

Comment: I tried to ask a clarifying question but it says I have to wait a couple of days because my question was not received well be the community.   What did I ask that was so objectionable?  And BTW my question did not get answered.

Comment: You asked for a reference and I gave you one in my earlier comment. I see no need to reopen this question

Answer (score 1):

HTMLCollection objects are array-like.

The elements with the class name are available through the integer properties of the object.

`x[0]` is the first element that matched.

`innerHTML` is a property of an Element not of the HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 0):

[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a "live" [node list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). A node list is a generic term for a collection of nodes, which are the fundamental building blocks in the Document Object Model.

This collection/node list is an ["array-like" object](https://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/) and can be iterated over.

But, `.getElementsByClassName()` is a very old API and, as I mentioned, returns a "live" node list that causes the DOM to be re-scanned upon each access attempt to ensure that you always get the most up to date results. This can be useful in some edge cases where elements are being dynamically added or removed, but because of the fact the the DOM is re-scanned every time you access it, it can hurt performance dramatically [and therefore should rarely, if ever, be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991).

The lines of code you shared:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example"); 
x[0].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
```

don't show you using what's returned by `.getElementsByClassName()`, **the second line is accessing one of the [individual nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) within the node list (the first one to be exact) and that individual node is what `.innerHTML` is being called on.**

Now, those lines are absolutely terrible lines from a performance standpoint because if you are only interested in the first match in the collection, you shouldn't scan the whole DOM and then just use only the first match. Instead, just search for the first match with [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Additionally, don't use `.innerHTML` when the string you are working with doesn't contain any HTML as `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications.

W3 Schools is very well known as being a very poor resource to use as the content there is very often outdated, incomplete, or flat out wrong. Instead use one of the most trusted authorities on web development, [The Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/).

The modern replacement for it is [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which you can pass any valid CSS selector into and it returns a static node list. If you need to update the list, you can just call it again as needed.

So, with all that said, the better way to accomplish what the two lines you shared do is this:

```
// Find the first node that has the example class and 
// set its text to "Hello World!"
var x = document.querySelector(".example").textContent = "Hello World!";
```